# How to consolidate a list of coordinates into subgroup if they are close to each within 2 or less unit distance in x direction?

Tags: list, sorting, tcl, grouping, coordinates

I have a list(a) of coordinates as follow.

```
list a = {{1 2} {5 6} {1 5} {5 8} {1 8}}
```

I would like the result to be broken into two lists, b and c. How do I do it in tcl?

```
list b = {{1 2} {1 5} {1 8}}

list c = {{5 6} {5 8}}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way, which returns a list of lists you can break up into individual variables or do whatever else is needed:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

# Return a list of lists of coords. Each sublist is of coordinates with
# an x value $distance or less units away from each other.
# Each coordinate will only appear once in the result.
proc partition {coords {distance 2}} {
    set groups {}
    foreach coord $coords {
        set found false
        for {set n 0} {$n < [llength $groups]} {incr n} {
            if {abs([lindex $groups $n 0 0] - [lindex $coord 0]) <= $distance} {
                lset groups $n [linsert [lindex $groups $n] end $coord]
                set found true
                break
            }
        }
        if {!$found} {
            lappend groups [list $coord]
        }
    }
    return $groups
}

set coords {{1 2} {5 6} {1 5} {5 8} {1 8}}
foreach group [partition $coords] {
    puts $group
}
```

when run outputs

```
{1 2} {1 5} {1 8}
{5 6} {5 8}
```

Basically, for each element of the input list, see if its first number is `<=` 2 of an existing element of the output list of lists, and if so, add it to that sublist. If there are no matches, append a new sublist to the result.